# Action bar support library is not working properly

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have developed a sample application using action bar support library. But in the devices which are with OS version 4.0.4, it's not appearing as expected. Please check with the screenshots.

The following screenshot is taken from the device with OS version 2.3.3

[image]

The below screenshot is taken from the device with OS version 4.0.4. In this the menu options are coming in middle of the screen which is expected to come at bottom.

[image]

Any idea about this?

Here is the activity.

```
public class DropDownActionBar extends ActionBarActivity implements OnNavigationListener {
private ActionBar mActionBar;

private TextView mTextView;

ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dropdown_actionbar_layout);

    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dropITEM_tv);

    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.action_list, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.frag_action_bar_items, menu);

    MenuItem mShareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share_PIC);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mShareItem);
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private Intent getShareIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    return intent;
}

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int pos, long itemID) {
    String[] res = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.action_list);
    Log.v("SELECTED_ITEM   ", "ITEM " + pos);

    mTextView.setText("Item " + res[pos]);
    return true;
}
```

}

and here the frag_action_bar_items menu layout.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:actionbardemo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_itemsearch"
    actionbardemo:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    actionbardemo:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
    android:title="Search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share_PIC"
    actionbardemo:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    actionbardemo:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share Pic"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_staron"
    actionbardemo:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/star_big_on"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_star_on"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_staroff"
    actionbardemo:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/star_big_off"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_star_off"/>
```

Comment: Could you share some code (XML layouts, classes)?

Comment: You want to put the action bar at the bottom or top of the screen? The standard way is the top.

Comment: @YoannHercouet, I want to put at the bottom only.

Comment: You can have a look to SplitActionBar: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar

Comment: @YoannHercouet, I am following the same. My concern is it's working for all the devices except in the devices which are with ICS 4.0.4 version.